# Optimizing a group by/where in/min() query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, query-performance

Assume I have a table that looks like such (The actual column names of my real table would only make things harder to explain, so I have created a mimic that behaves similarly).

id  |  cond1  | cond2  | cond3  | cond4  | cond5  |  start  |  end  | val1  | val2  |

`cond1` - `cond5` are condition values, and each one can take on about 2-6 values.
For example, `cond1` belongs to the subset ('hold', 'setup').

`start` - `end` are varchar strings (potentially quite long) and represent the start point and end point of a path.

`val1` - `val2` are values. They represent the time required to complete the path, etc.

After data has been uploaded to this table it is static. There are no future updates/inserts.

The basic goal of a query sent to this table is such:

1. Grab all rows that meet certain condition requirements. (For example, `cond1` must equal `'setup'`, `cond2` must belong to some subset of the set of values it can take on, `cond3` must belong to some subset of the set of values it can take on, `cond4` must belong to some subset of the set of values it can take on, and we will say `cond5` is ignored for now).
2. Uniquify this resultset on end where val1 is at its minimum.

Essentially, I am trying to find the number of failing ends and what their worst failure was under the condition requirements.

The query I have been using up til this point is below.

```
select cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5, start, end, **min(val1)**, val2
from table 
where cond1='setup' 
  and cond2 in ('...') 
  and cond3 in ('...') 
  and cond4 in ('...') 
**group by end**
```

When these tables start to grow really big, (right now one of the tables I am using has 2.5 million rows), queries of this type take forever (aka 30 seconds).

I've played around with some indexes, but often times MySQL chooses not to use them. For example, a likely query is one `where cond1='hold'` and every other condition can be anything. The number of hold rows GREATLY outnumbers the number of setup rows (its safe to assume 98% of the rows are hold), so a full table scan in that scenario makes sense.

I guess my question is where am I screwing up? I am positive many of you can do a lot better than 30 seconds, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the table is static and you have bad cardinality just create a new table with the desired results.2.5 million rows is not much at all for mysql.

Comment: The query doesn't make sense (not completely at least.) If for example, there are many rows that match the conditions for a specific `end` value, which of the many `cond2` should be displayed? Which `cond3`, ... etc? Which `val2`? Only the `min(val1)` will give you a determinate result.

Comment: I guess I assumed that the cond2, cond3, etc values grabbed would come from the row where min(val1) was found. If that is an incorrect assumption, then you are quite right, my query is dumb.

Comment: This sounds like a variant of the classic "groupwise max" problem.  [_My blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) provides a couple of efficient ways to do such, depending on specific requirements.  (It should be easy to change from "max" to "min".)